# Как сделать выполнение fetch в цикле for последовательным?

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

Получаю через fetch массив с идентификаторами пользователей. Затем нужно циклом пройти по ним и подставить значения в другой запрос: `` fetch(`${someUrl}${userID}`) ``. Сделать нужно так чтобы каждый следующий fetch запрос выполнялся только после завершения предыдущего. Понимаю что нужно копать в сторону async/await, но для меня это сложновато на данный момент. Прошу помочь с кодом.

```
getUsers() {
  fetch(`${url-get-users-id}`)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error("Error");
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {    
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         fetch(
          `${get-users-detail-info-by-id}/${data[i]}`
        ).then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
          }
          else {
            throw new Error("Error");
          }
        })
        ,then((data) => {
          this.usersInfo = data;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
}
```

Comment: Надеюсь решение Вам кто-нибудь даст. Моё пришлось удалить. т.к модераторам важнее ответа, его оформление. Что-то я наелся `ru`-веткой этого сайта. В `en` люди адекватнее...

Comment: @ФеоктистПупырышкин Кусок кода с синтаксическими ошибками без пояснения, что там вообще происходит, ну так себе. Вам надо было удалить ваш комментарий, добавить его в само тело ответа и поправить синтаксис. И да... Это не модераторы, а такие же участники сообщества, как и вы.

Comment: @ФеоктистПупырышкин вам всего лишь написали, что **вся информация, которая должна быть в ответе - должна быть в ответе**, а не в комментариях к нему. Если у вас не хватает способности этого понять, то надо пенять не других, а себя

Comment: @ФеоктистПупырышкин на en люди просто толерантнее ко всем людям с особенностями восприятия. В итоге это приводит к помойке из непонятно чего. Видимо вам ближе такое мышление, когда можно что угодно нахлобучить, лишь бы было, а не так, чтоб было правильно. С таким мышлением мы, конечно, сделать ничего не можем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, в данном случае удобнее будет воспользоваться `async`/`await`.

Для переделывания достаточно заменить `then` на `await`, а `.catch` на `try..catch`, а также указать что функция теперь `async`

```
async getUsers() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${url-get-users-id}`);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Error");
    }
    const data = await response.json();

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${get-users-detail-info-by-id}/${data[i]}`
      );
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Error");
      }
      try {
        const data = await response.json();
        this.usersInfo = data;
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
      };
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  };
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш код работает. Это мой первый вопрос на Stackoverflow и я немного воодушевлен))) По мере роста своих навыков, постараюсь тоже помогать людям))))

Answer (score 0):

Создадим асинхронную функцию, которая будет делать вызов для каждого элемента массива и дожидаться ответа.

```
async function getUserDetails(users) {
  // Если пользлователей нет, то выходим
  if (!users.length) return;
  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    // Ждем ответа
    await fetch(`${get-users-detail-info-by-id}/${users[i]}`)
      .then((response) => response.json()) // переводим ответ в json
      .then((data) => {
        // в data полученный ответ по пользователю
        // Сюда надо добавить вашу обработку данных
      });
  }
}
```

В основной функции добавляем ее вызов и передаем полученный массив

```
getUsers() {
  fetch(`${url-get-users-id}`)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error("Error");
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      // Передаем полученный массив в отдельную фукнцию
      getUserDetails(data);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
}
```

Если есть зависимость от контекста исполнения, то тут уже надо смотреть более предметно на код. В частности, где объявлена переменная `get-users-detail-info-by-id` и что такое `this.usersInfo`

Comment: лучше не смешивать then и await - сильно запутывает, учитывая что может потребоваться вернуть данные

Comment: @Grundy Если потребуется возвращать данные, то будет, скорее всего и другое решение, т.к. возможно данные надо вернуть из основной функции `getUsers`, а делая ее асинхронной, надо что то делать в том месте, где она вызывается. Тут одно цепляется за другое. И кстати, если потребуется вернуть значение из `getUserDetails` то then успешно дождется этих данных.

Comment: в цикле будут проблемы при такой записи

Comment: @Grundy Какие например? Я вот смотрю на цикл и не понимаю, какие проблемы в данном случае могут быть(если бы понимал, то не написал бы так)

Comment: данные же собрать вместе

Comment: @Grundy Если надо данные из ответов сохранять и потом скопом вернуть, то добавить какой то аккумулятор(массив допустим) и туда складировать ответы, потом махом вернуть, это + 2 строки кода. И опять же, в самом цикле проблем не вижу...

Comment: Проблема в then внутри цикла, и что это может запутывать когда используется вместе с await

Comment: @Grundy Ну это не проблема кода, а вопрос восприятия этого кода. Т.е. разговор о синтасическом сахаре или как более понятнее написать. Да, можно все then выкинуть, выделить переменную, далее работать с этой переменной и await, но практического смысла я не вижу. Я лично прекрасно воспринимаю код и понимаю что там происходит. Перепишу на await, придет другой и скажет, что с then лучше читается... потом любители var и promise(async/await они плохо воспринимают и путаются) появятся... Всем не угодить по стилю написания кода.

Comment: _Т.е. разговор о синтасическом сахаре или как более понятнее написать_  - и именно про это и был самый первый комментарий ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: _Перепишу на await, придет другой и скажет, что с then лучше читается_ - в первом комментарии было не про то, что then лучше/хуже async/await - а то что их лучше не смешивать ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯