# Постоянный вызов асинхронных функций

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, async-await

Как в js можно реализовать вызов функций по типу

```
fetch -> запрос пришел, все нормально -> fetch -> ...
и так пока не обработаются все элементы и сервер не вернет конечный вариант.
```

Мы не знаем сколько придется сделать асинхронных запросов, пока сервер об этом не ответит. Но нам нужно делать асинхронный запросы один за другим.

Comment: [Последовательные запросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1572751)

Comment: @SwaD Получается я должен вызвать одну функцию с одними условиями, а потом сделать опять запрос на тот же сервер, но уже в цикле с теми же условиями?

Comment: Вместо дублирования вопросов, стоит добавить необходимую информацию в исходный вопрос

Comment: _Как в js можно реализовать вызов функций по типу_ - в твоем исходном вопросе, код именно это и делает.

Comment: @Grundy Там просто вопрос закрыт был, буду знать, спасибо

Comment: Вопросы закрывают, для того, чтобы их отредактировали и добавили больше информации - в плашке об этом как раз и написано.